Reload stream provider when nested child object changes
Description
I have the following object structure, making use of the firestore nested collections:
class A {
  final String name;
  final List<B> bs;
  final String createdBy;
}

To retrieve data I wrote a stream:
Stream<List<A>> get allA{
    return aCollection.snapshots().asyncMap((snapshot) async {
      return Future.wait(snapshot.docs.map((doc) async {
        final bSnapshots=
            await bCollection(doc.reference).get();
        final bs =
            bSnapshots.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
        final a = A(
          name: doc.data().name,
          bs: bs,
          createdBy: doc.data().createdBy,
        );
        return a;
      }).toList());
    });
  }

I display all data in a ListView, which gets it from a StreamProvider:
return StreamProvider<List<A>>.value(
        lazy: false,
        value: DatabaseService().allA,
        initialData: [],
        child: ...

In the child widget:
final as = Provider.of<List<A>>(context);

Problem
When I make a change in the sub collection "bs" the StreamProvider for List<A> is not triggered, and so it doesn't reload the ListView. Is there any possibility to notify or hard reload the StreamProvider?
I already tried to adapt the hashcode of class A:
@override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return other is A &&
        other.name == name &&
        ListEquality().equals(other.bs, bs) &&
        other.createdBy == createdBy;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode =>
      name.hashCode ^ ListEquality().hash(bs) ^ createdBy.hashCode;

That sounded promising to me, but it didn't work.
